# Issues with a mex mxGetDoubles() function when compiling

Tags: c, matlab, mex

Whenever I try to compile my very simple testing mex function, I get an error

> "undefined reference to `mxGetDoubles'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm using Matlab R2019a, mingw-w64 6.3.0. The example c file they give (explore.c) compiles just fine and also uses `mxGetDoubles()`.

I've tried using `mxGetPr()` and even though they say they don't recommend it and that it shouldn't work after matlab R2018a in the documentation, that works just fine.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"



void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]){
    mxDouble *vertices;


    vertices = mxGetDoubles(prhs[1]);//mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

}
```

Comment: The message doesn't seem to come from the compiler itself but either from the linker (meaning: a library is missing) or from the loader (meaning: a dll is missing).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It's a matlab error when I call ``` mex fileName.c ```, but again, the weird part is that both the older function and the example c file that uses the same function both work.

Comment: It seems to be related to 32/64 bits somehow, but  I haven't found a solution.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've just tried it using "mex -R2018a fileName.c" and that compiled without an error. I'm just testing it now to see if it actually works as well. It might have to do with the matlab interleaved API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, the fix was kind of easy, instead of calling `mex fileName.c` , I had to use `mex -R2018a fileName.c`.

But this doens't answer why `mex explore.c` works even though it uses the same function, so if anyone knows why, I'd be really interested. I'm assuming it has something to do with the interleaved complex API, but could be anything tbh.

Answer (score 3):

Because in explore.c there is the test, line 686:

```
 #if MX_HAS_INTERLEAVED_COMPLEX
```

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the answers (assuming you only use real, double variables):

1. Either use

   ```
   vertices = mxGetDoubles(prhs[1]);
   ```

   with the command

   ```
   mex -R2018a my_system_function.c
   ```

   (as you proposed)
2. Or you can also use

   ```
   #if MX_HAS_INTERLEAVED_COMPLEX
       vertices = mxGetDoubles(prhs[1]);
   #else
       vertices = mxGetPr(prhs[1]); // pointer to real part
   #endif
   ```

   with the command

   ```
   mex my_system_function.c
   ```

   (as mpre hinted - see code in "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\extern\examples\mex\explore.c").

In my case, I used it do retrieve the function parameters in the update function:

```
static void mdlUpdate(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{
    const real_T   *u    = (const real_T*) ssGetInputPortSignal(S,0);
    real_T         *x    = ssGetRealDiscStates(S);
    const mxArray  *p_mx = (const mxArray *) ssGetSFcnParam(S, 0);

#if MX_HAS_INTERLEAVED_COMPLEX
    const mxDouble *p    = mxGetDoubles(p_mx);
#else
    const double   *p    = mxGetPr(p_mx); // pointer to real part
#endif

   //...

}
```